# Why does this code print "Woof" twice when executed even though I only called super.speak() once?

Tags: java, inheritance, super

```
public class Dog
{
    public void speak()
    {
        System.out.println("woof!");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Dog d = new Dog();
        d.speak();
        Dog b = new Beagle();
        b.speak();
    }
}

class Beagle extends Dog
{
    public void speak()
    {
        super.speak();
        System.out.println("arf arf");
    }
}
```

This is super confusing, because I am not sure why the speak method of the super class is being run twice even if I called it just once. The final result is "Woof \n Woof \n arf arf".

Comment: Because you call `d.speak()` and `b.speak()`. And in `Beagle` you invoke the superclass' version of the overridden method with `super.speak()`.

Comment: So does everything in the superclass main method automatically get executed when a sub class is run? Because then, shouldnt "woof" be printed three times, because of the fact that I called d.speak, b.speak, and super.speak?

Comment: No, when you override a method the original method is no longer executed, _unless you call `super.xxx(...)` in the override_.

Comment: You could very easily experiment with this yourself by adding additional print statements to determine sequencing.

Comment: Or run it in a debugger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See annotations in comments.

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Dog d = new Dog();
    d.speak();  // calls Dog.speak() -> prints "woof!"
    Dog b = new Beagle();
    b.speak(); // calls Beagle.speak() -> 
               // prints "woof!" via call to super.speak() 
               // and then "arf arf"
}
```

Answer (score 3):

> I am not sure why the speak method of the super class is being run twice even if I called it just once.*.

You call it twice.

1. You call it directly when you invoke d.speak();
2. Then you call it indirectly when you invoke b.speak() since b.speak() first invokes super.speak().

Edit:

> because we are calling b.speak, d.speak -

b.speak() does NOT display "woof" directly. There is no println(...) statement to display "woof".

It invokes super.speak(). The super.speak() simply means execute the code in the speak() method of the parent class which happens to be the Dog class. So "woof" is displayed.

Then it displays "arf arf".

So:

1. d.speak() causes "woof" to be displayed.
2. b.speak() causes "woof" and "arf arf"to be displayed.

Change your code to be:

```
System.out.println("Dog is about to speak:");
d.speak();
Dog b = new Beagle();
System.out.println("Beagle is about to speak:");
b.speak();
```

to see the output as described above.

Comment: I am still confused on why it doesn't print then three times. I didnt write this code, so pardon me for not understanding how it works, but as far as I know shouldnt "woof" be printed three times then, because we are calling b.speak, d.speak and super.speak? Sorry for the confusion, I am a little bit new to inheritance.

Comment: `b.speak()` does not print Woof except through its call to `super.speak()`.

Comment: Ok, got it thank you so much, I think I understand it much better now. Thanks a lot senior dev!

Comment: @ShyamVyas and yet you "accepted" a different answer?

Answer (score 0):

Basically you are making the call twice when you invoque `super.speak()` in `Beagle` class. If you want to eliminate the duplicate call, you might want to delete the `super.speak()` call. When you call super, you are invoking the super class method.

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Dog d = new Dog();
        d.speak();
        Dog b = new Beagle();
        b.speak();

    }
}

class Dog
{
    public void speak()
    {
        System.out.println("woof!");
    }

}

class Beagle extends Dog
{
    @Override
    public void speak()
    {
//        super.speak();
        System.out.println("arf arf");
    }
}
```

Also, you might want to annotate the Beagle.speak method with `@Override`, so that is understandable that you are overriding the method from the super class.

**Side Note**:
*I have also separated the main method from the Super class... If you are getting started with Java programming, I would take a look at **SOLID** principles, first one been "**S**" for **Single Responsibility**. Basically this means that every class and method should have only one responsibility.*